# Why is my vim bash command auto-completion reporting error?

Tags: bash, vim

Hi today for unknown reason, if I typed the following command "vim \tab" in bash terminal to hopefully get an auto-completion, I get the following error:

```
$ vim bash: command substitution: line 22: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
bash: command substitution: line 22: `        }'
```

This error does not happen if I typed '\tab` at the end of other commands such as 'ls', or even an alias of vim such as 'alias v=vim'.

This error does not happen in another gnome-terminal, either.

Not sure what is causing this (a vim plugin?). Any idea? thanks.

Comment: Vim is not involved at all in bash completion. Look elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Found the root cause. I created an alias done, and the "done" conflicts with the bash keyword "done". Problem solved by renamed the alias.